# Problem with Image Slider in IE - Bug?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, joomla

I'm having a problem with my image slider in IE. On my home page I have a banner which has an image slider. When you switch between images on this slider, a black outline appears around the edges of the banner image. The image slider itself is done in jquery, but the website is a Joomla CMS website.

I've researched into this, and I thought it could be a Png IE bug, problems with transparency, as the images are rounded rectangles. I've put the code to fix this bug in my CSS, but this doesn't seem to change anything, so i was wondering if anybody else had some suggestions?

My website is [www.myramis.com](http://www.myramis.com).

Comment: Do you mean the black lines on the corners, which lasts something like 1 second?

Comment: Yes, its only very subtle, but I'm curious why this happens in IE and not any of the other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the end of your document before the </body> tag:

```
<style type="text/css">
    * html #png-ie /* ie6 hack */
        { filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='/to_my_png/imageIE.png', sizingMethod='scale')); }
    *+ html #png-ie /* ie7 hack */
        { filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='/to_my_png/imageIE.png', sizingMethod='scale')); }
</style>
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this but it still shows the black lines on the corners. I have IE 8 and it happens on this too.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it the outline to be less prominent using the following code, but I think perhaps I have to do something in the jquery to get it to completely disappear:

```
    .slide img {
        background: transparent;

 -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#00FFFFFF,endColorstr=#00FFFFFF)";
     /* IE8 */   
         filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#00FFFFFF,endColorstr=#00FFFFFF);
     /* IE6 & 7 */      
        zoom: 1; }
```

Perhaps somebody knows of a jquery fix I could use for the same problem which would perhaps elminate the black outline completely?